# What is wrong with this implementation of the arithmetic derivative?

Tags: python, math

The following is a refactoring of the Python code found [here](https://oeis.org/A003415) for computing the arithmetic derivative.

```py
from sympy import factorint

def f(n):
    result = factorint(n)
    result = result.items()
    result = [int(n*e/p) for p, e in result]
    result = sum(result)
    result = result if n > 1 else 0
    return result
```

[It can be shown](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4454303/230586) that the arithmetic derivative of a primer number to the power of itself will be a fixed point. Feel free to scrutinize the proof if you think that is where the issue lies.

[A051674](https://oeis.org/A051674) is the sequence of primes to the power of themselves in the usual ordering of the primes. Among them is 827240261886336764177, but when I call the above function on it I do not get the correct result:

```py
>>> f(827240261886336764177)
827240261886336827392
```

In fact, tabulating all of the listed sequence members evaluated by f reveals that entries before that work, and entries after that break.

| p_n | f(p_n) |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 4 |
| 27 | 27 |
| 3125 | 3125 |
| 823543 | 823543 |
| 285311670611 | 285311670611 |
| 302875106592253 | 302875106592253 |
| 827240261886336764177 | 827240261886336827392 |
| 1978419655660313589123979 | 1978419655660313627328512 |
| 20880467999847912034355032910567 | 20880467999847910614749358850048 |
| 2567686153161211134561828214731016126483469 | 2567686153161211279596267358657515496669184 |

So it seems that the numbers becoming too large might be a problem. Why does this function fail on these larger cases?

Comment: Maybe a float precision problem in `int(n*e/p)` for large `n`.

Comment: If in the line with the `int(n*e/p)`, `n`, `e` and `p` are all integers (`int` types), maybe try to simply write `n*e//p` instead, to only use integer operations.

Comment: @Krafpy Yes, that suggestion fixed all the above cases. Please post this as an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dealing with integers, try to only use integer operations. Since in the line

```
result = [int(n*e/p) for p, e in result]
```

`n`, `e` and `p` are integers (`int` types), simply write `n*e//p` instead of `int(n*e/p)`.